# how to send paramter from c# to excel and save the data there

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

i have 2 issues what i am facing

- i have an dataset where i need to send the data from dataset to an
  excel once data in dumped in that location.
- i need to change the column headers make them bold

2:
  Above the report headers we should pass 1 parameter that will be the name(Employee details) from c# we need to pass as an parameter to it.
  it can change what ever parameter we pass it on.

ex:
  Reportname: Employee details

```
  Name      EmpID   city
  Arun        11       bangalore
  Kiran       56       chennai
  Rahul       23       pune
```

Comment: What are the questions to your issues? Do you have some code?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, but I did not test it. Thank you to [Deborah Kurata](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/23/writing-data-from-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx) for writing a large part of the code below.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;

private void ExportToExcel(DataTable Table, string ReportName, string Filename)
{
  Excel.Application oXL;
  Excel.Workbook oWB;
  Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
  Excel.Range oRange;

  // Start Excel and get Application object.
  oXL = new Excel.Application();

  // Set some properties
  oXL.Visible = true;
  oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

  // Get a new workbook.
  oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);

  // Get the active sheet
  oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet ;
  oSheet.Name = "Report";

  int rowCount = 3;
  foreach (DataRow dr in Table.Rows)
  {
      for (int i = 1; i < Table.Columns.Count+1; i++)
      {
          // Add the header the first time through
          if (rowCount==3)
          {
              oSheet.Cells[1, i] = Table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
              rowCount++;
          }
          oSheet.Cells[rowCount, i] = dr[i - 1].ToString();
      }
      rowCount++;
  }

  // Resize the columns
  oRange = oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[3, 1],
                oSheet.Cells[rowCount, Table.Columns.Count]);
  oRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

  // Set report title *after* we adjust column widths
  oSheet.Cells[1,1] = ReportName;

  // Save the sheet and close
  oSheet = null;
  oRange = null;
  oWB.SaveAs(Filename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
      Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
      Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
      Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
      Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
  oWB.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
  oWB = null;
  oXL.Quit();

  // Clean up
  // NOTE: When in release mode, this does the trick
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  GC.Collect();
}
```